# PostgreSQL: dealing with array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a column available_sizes in PostgreSQL table with a type array: text[]

```
select available_sizes from products;

 {37,38,39,40}
...
```

Sometimes I need to check what rows contain certain values, e.g. both 39 and 40, so I tried to do it this way:

```
select * 
from products 
where available_sizes && ('{39, 40}');
```

Returns rows containing either 39 or 40

```
select * 
from products 
where available_sizes = ANY ('{41, 42}');
```

Returns an error: "could not find array type for data type text[]"

How would you solve this please? Sorry, not an expert in SQL/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` is the "overlaps" operator which is [described as](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) "have elements in common"

What you are looking for is the "contains" operator `@>` that checks if all elements of the array to the right are contained in the array to the left:

```
select * 
from products 
where available_sizes @> ('{39, 40}');
```